# Know if a Readable stream can be read from

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a stream in flow mode. I want to check that it is readable before continuing to interact with it:

```
function do_some_stuff_with_stream(stream)
{
    if (stream.canBeReadFrom())
        stream.read(10)...
}
```

In other words, has either end or error happened before hand. Now, the way stream seems to work is that end will keep being fired every time you listen to it (even if it has already ended, so I guess that can kind of be used):

```
function do_some_stuff_with_stream(stream)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        var data = stream.read(10);

        if (data !== null)
            resolve(data);
        else
        {
            stream.on("end", reject); // this will happen even if it ended beforehand.
            stream.on("readable", function()
            {
                do_some_stuff_with_stream(stream).then(resolve);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

However, "error" does not behave this way, so if I'm passed an error stream, I sit around waiting forever instead of rejecting.

Comment: Did you try checking `stream.readable`? If it's not readable, just `reject()` right away.

Comment: Does that change in response to error? It certainly doesn't change to false after "end" has occurred. The API docs seem to mention nothing about it, but I think its to distinguish Writable vs Readable streams (or that can do both), not to let you know if its in a readable state.

Comment: It should change to indicate whether the stream is actually readable, not to indicate what *type* of stream it is. What node version are you using?

Comment: 0.10.36 The following code returns true, despite no data in the stream:        var Readable = require('stream').PassThrough;
var rs = new Readable;
console.log(rs.readable)

Comment: new (require('stream').PassThrough)().readable returns true in 0.12 as well. So it seems to just say "yes this is a readable thing", not "there is data to be read". I also don't know how to simulate an error, so i don't know if it would become not readable at that point

Comment: If i do readableStream.push(null) (signifying the end), readable remains true. Ah but if I then read once its goes false, I'll assume it works for the error case as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading from the stream buffer data event and you are using socket.io streams and node and assuming by "can be read from" you mean the data is now usable, and not that the stream is literally of type Readable

```

```
cstream.on("data", function (data) {
    buffer += data.toString();

    if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(buffer.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
    replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
    replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {
        var tdata = JSON.parse(buffer);
        //add it to our main stage
        drawBiome(worldStage,tdata);
        socket.emit("drawBiomeAvatars");   
    }     

});
```

```

the if checks if the buffer is a "valid" json string before deciding to use the data.